# Force UITabBarController to push to root

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When I add views to my `UINavigationController` within a Tab and I then touch that tab again it pops to the root view. I was just wondering, is there any way to pop this to the root programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, configure a delegate for the tab bar. When the proper tab is pressed, call the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method on the nav controller.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks. Don't know what I was thinking when I questioned this, must have been a late night :p

Comment: No prob—glad to be of service